# VS2010 SFINAE and function overload error

Tags: visual-c++, overloading, sfinae

I have code like this, that compiles fines in all compiler I've tested except VS2010.
I'm trying not to use C++11 specific features here, so it can still compile on outdated compiler like gcc 4.1.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Simplified variant class
struct Var
{
    template <class T>
    Var(T t) {}

    Var(void) {}
};
// Simplified argument array class
struct FuncArgs
{

};


/** Make a wrapper around the given function */
template <int line, typename Ret, Ret Func()>
Var WrapFuncT(const FuncArgs & args)
{
    Var ret;
    ret = Func(); return ret;
}
/** Make a wrapper around the given function */
template <int line, void Func()>
Var WrapFuncT(const FuncArgs & args)
{
    Var ret;
    Func(); return ret;
}
// Unary
template <int line, typename Ret, typename Arg1, Ret Func(Arg1)>
Var WrapFuncT(const FuncArgs & args)
{
    Var ret; Arg1 arg;
    ret = Func(arg);                   
    return ret;
}
template <int line, typename Arg1, void Func(Arg1)>
Var WrapFuncT(const FuncArgs & args)
{
    Var ret; Arg1 arg;
    Func(arg);                         
    return ret;
}
// Binary
template <int line, typename Ret, typename Arg1, typename Arg2, Ret Func(Arg1, Arg2)>
Var WrapFuncT(const FuncArgs & args)
{
    Var ret; Arg1 arg1; Arg2 arg2;
    ret = Func(arg1, arg2);                   
    return ret;
}
template <int line, typename Arg1, typename Arg2, void Func(Arg1, Arg2)>
Var WrapFuncT(const FuncArgs & args)
{
    Var ret; Arg1 arg1; Arg2 arg2;
    Func(arg1, arg2);                         
    return ret;
}
#define WrapFunc(X, Y, ...) &WrapFuncT<__LINE__, X, Y, ## __VA_ARGS__ >   

int testFunc()
{
    return 42;
}

void testFunc2(int value)
{
    cout<<value<<endl;
}   

typedef Var (*NamedFunc)(const FuncArgs &);

int main()
{
   NamedFunc a, b;
   a = WrapFunc(int, testFunc);
   b = WrapFunc(int, testFunc2);

}
```

Visual studio 2010 compiler chokes on this with error:

```
In line 'a = WrapFunc(int, testFunc);' : error C2440: 'specialization' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void (__cdecl *const )(int)'
        This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
        error C2973: 'Type::WrapFuncT' : invalid template argument 'int (__cdecl *)(void)'

In line 'template <int line, typename Arg1, void Func(Arg1)>' : see declaration of 'Type::WrapFuncT'
```

Seems like VS2010 does not find the former definition `template < int line, typename Ret, Ret Func(void) >` with `Ret = int` for `int testFunc(void)` function, and instead tries and errors on the `template < int line, typename Arg1, void Func(Arg1) >`.

If I comment the later, then it compiles fine, so it is *able* to find the former overload.

I've tried to solve this in numerous way, none worked, as I need to "capture" a pointer to function in a same signature function `Var (*) (const FuncArgs &)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a generic template function and using specialization with structure, something like:

```
namespace detail
{

// class to specialize for each function type
template <int line, typename F, F f> struct helper_wrapper;

// partial specialization
template <int line, typename Ret, Ret (&Func)()>
struct helper_wrapper<line, Ret (&)(void), Func>
{
    Var operator()(const FuncArgs&) const
    {
        Var ret;
        ret = Func();
        return ret;
    }
};

// partial specialization
template <int line, void (&Func)()>
struct helper_wrapper<line, void (&)(), Func>
{
    Var operator()(const FuncArgs&) const
    {
        Var ret;
        Func();
        return ret;
    }
};

// partial specialization
template <int line, typename Ret, typename Arg1, Ret (&Func)(Arg1)>
struct helper_wrapper<line, Ret (&)(Arg1), Func>
{
    Var operator()(const FuncArgs&) const
    {
        Var ret;
        Arg1 arg;
        ret = Func(arg);
        return ret;
    }
};

// partial specialization
template <int line, typename Arg1, void (&Func)(Arg1)>
struct helper_wrapper<line, void (&)(Arg1), Func>
{
    Var operator()(const FuncArgs&) const
    {
        Var ret;
        Arg1 arg;
        Func(arg);
        return ret;
    }
};

// other partial specialization omitted. 

}

// The general function
template <int line, typename F, F f>
Var WrapFuncT(const FuncArgs& arg) { return detail::helper_wrapper<line, F, f>()(arg); }

// The helper macro
#define WrapFunc(X, Y)    &WrapFuncT<__LINE__, X, Y>
```

And then call it that way:

```
a = WrapFunc(int(&)(), testFunc);
b = WrapFunc(void(&)(int), testFunc2);
```

Comment: I would have preferred not to write the function's signature in the macro. Also, this code still does not work in VS2010 with error `error C2440: typecast can not convert from 'overloaded function' to Var (*) (const FuncArgs &)`

Comment: Ok, fixed the last error by replacing references to pointers for the function. VS2010 seems to consider the type `Ret (&) (Arg)` (instead of `Ret (*) (Arg)` even if instantiated with `&func`